# How to set Input Language for Textbox in Silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I can set input language for textbox in WPF like that:

```
InputLanguageManager.SetInputLanguage(textBoxName, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru"));
```

But there is not InputLanguageManager class in System.Windows.Input assembly.
How can i change input language in Silverlight?

Comment: IMHO, you can not set input language in silverlight due to sandbox restrictions. In full trust applications you can try p/invoke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing user input language is not supported in Silverlight. Because silverlight is partial trusted and cannot access to system resource for security reason.

For further details, please check below link

[User input language in silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470128%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)